Having trouble figuring out adding an animated/transitioning "read more" with JavaScript
**I've never used JS before and I'm teaching myself how to code. **
I am currently coding a personal website/blog and I wanted to shorten the pages by cutting off each post with a read more that extends on click. I found this codepen and it seems to work fine on the site, but when I try applying it to my blog it doesn't work. The page I'm using isn't live, just from my desktop folder and opened in my browser.
I have a file called script.js and have linked it to my blog file as such:
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
I copied the JS section from the codepen and put it in the linked file, the CSS in my style.css, and the same format in my html. However, peeking at the console after this does not work, it throws this error:
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    <anonymous> file:///C:/Users/kashy/Desktop/le neocities/script.js:1

Most likely an extremely simple fix but I've no clue! Thank you...

On a side note, Codepen does not directly show all of the script that it is injected from the code editor. In order to find all the scripts that the author has injected, you can click on Settings -> JS to see the external script that is loaded (in this case jQuery)
